# Symfony 2 / Doctrine 2, ORDER BY with BIT_AND operator

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to retreive some tsks in a database, and sort them with a binary operation on a field.
Here is what I want :

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('t')
                    ->from('MyBundle:Task', 't');
    $query->orderBy('BIT_AND(t.options, 1)', 'DESC');
```

I don't want to have one field for each "option", so all my options are "bits" in a field.

The previous code isn't working.
I've tried to do :

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('t', 'BIT_AND(t.options, 1) as myoption')
                    ->from('MyBundle:Task', 't');
    $query->orderBy('myoption', 'DESC');
```

But in this case, I'm loosing the objects in relations... As my tasks are related to users, and I want to do $task->getUser() (or more precisely in twig : task.user)

So my question is :
- how can I sort my data on a binary operator ?
- how can I keep my objects hydrated correctly if I'm doing a multiple select ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Don't have much experience with applying functions to sorting parameters but it might work.  a.options should be t.options?  The doctrine manual does seem to imply that functions are only supported for SELECT, WHERE and HAVING clauses.  So your second approach is probably the way to go.  Echo out the generated sql and see what you get.

Comment: I don't understand with you have a `=` in your order by ?

Comment: It's an error in my question as I have simplified the real query. But in my query, the table name is good !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
                ->select('t')
                ->addSelect('BIT_AND(t.options, 1) AS HIDDEN option')
                ->from('MyBundle:Task', 't');
$query->orderBy('option', 'DESC');
```

It's working on doctrine 2.2+